# How do I create a new dataframe after merging on two columns independently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes where I want the resulting dataframe after merging to contain all elements of the left dataframe in either of the `n` columns as below:

```
df1:
    a    b
--  ---  ---
 0  a    bb
 1  aa   c
 2  b    cc
 3  bb   aa

df2:

      a    b
--  ---  ---
 0  a    e
 1  aa   d
 2  b    dd
 3  bb   ee
 4  c    a
 5  cc   d
 6  d    b
 7  dd   e
 8  e    aa
 9  ee   d
```

and the expected merge datfarme as:

```
merge:

    a    b
--  ---  ---
 0  a    e
 1  aa   d
 2  b    dd
 3  bb   ee
 4  c    a
 5  d    b
 6  e    aa
```

I have tried solutions:

```
merge = df1.merge(df2, on=['a', 'b'], how='outer')
merge = df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates()
```

However, its not resulting in the expected dataframe `merge`

How can I do the same in pandas?

The `merge` would contain all the column values present from `df1` in `df2` (vlookup but individual values of rows. as there are values in either columns of `df1` present in either cloumns of `df2`)

Sorry, I have not worded it better. I will try to explain if you have queries if any.

Comment: `merge = df1.append(df2).drop_duplicates()`

Comment: I am looking for a `merge` solution than an `append` one. Also, the resulting dataframe has `ee dd` which is not desired.

Comment: Hi, the code you provide does not produce the desired output. Also, why is the row `ee dd` not desired, compared to the others?

Comment: I apologise I have not written the question better. I will edit it to reflect what I want. I want a resulting dataframe which is a join of the smaller dataframe (left) containing all the elements of all the columns of the smaller dataframe (left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need check any column of `df2` by any column of `df1` use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with flatten `df1` by `np.ravel` and filter by at least one value per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
merge = df2[df2.isin(np.ravel(df1)).any(axis=1)]
print (merge)
    a   b
0   a   e
1  aa   d
2   b  dd
3  bb  ee
4   c   a
5  cc   d
6   d   b
8   e  aa
```

If need specify columns for test:

```
merge = df2[df2[['a','b']].isin(np.ravel(df1[['a','b']])).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: How do I specify which columns from `df1` should I look in `df2` if the need be?

Comment: @PyNoob_N - Use `df1[['a','b']]` instead `df1`

Comment: What about `df2` ? Do I need to specify columns similarly for `df2` ?

Comment: @PyNoob_N - added to answer.